# CompletableFuture runAsync vs supplyAsync, when to choose one over the other?

Tags: java, asynchronous, java-8, completable-future

What is the rationale for choosing one over the other? Only difference I could infer after reading the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#runAsync-java.lang.Runnable-) is that runAsync takes Runnable as an input parameter and supplyAsync takes Supplier as an input parameter.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36256337/completablefuture-supplyasync) stackoverflow post discusses the motivation behind using Supplier with supplyAsync method but it still does not answer when to prefer one over the other.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

[runAsync](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#runAsync-java.lang.Runnable-) takes Runnable as input parameter and returns `CompletableFuture<Void>`, which means it does not return any result.

```
CompletableFuture<Void> run = CompletableFuture.runAsync(()-> System.out.println("hello"));
```

But [suppyAsync](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#supplyAsync-java.util.function.Supplier-) takes Supplier as argument and returns the `CompletableFuture<U>` with result value, which means it does not take any input parameters but it returns result as output.

```
CompletableFuture<String> supply = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        System.out.println("Hello");
        return "result";
    });

 System.out.println(supply.get());  //result
```

**Conclusion :** So if you want the result to be returned, then choose `supplyAsync` or if you just want to run an async action, then choose `runAsync`.

Comment: Thanks @Deadpool, I should have read the documentation more carefully. Nice username btw.

Comment: why is Deadpool replying inside the Matrix?

Comment: now it's a Death note world (Light) @M..

Comment: @RyuzakiL so it took a little over two years uh! :-)